# Subclasses with generics of subclasses

Tags: java, generics, subclass

I have some issues with generics. I have a `BaseObject` with multiple sub-classes as well as a `BaseContainer<T extends BaseObject>` with sub-classes that correspond with `BaseObject` sub-classes.

```
public class TestClass extends BaseClass<BaseContainer<BaseObject>> {

    // method signature tied to BaseClass generic
    @Override
    private BaseContainer<BaseObject> createContainer() {
        BaseContainer<BaseObject> container;

        // example logic here to determine which container to use
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
            container = new Parent1Container(); // incompatible types
        } else {
            container = new Parent2Container(); // incompatible types
        }

        return container;
    }

    abstract static class BaseObject {}
    static class Parent1Object extends BaseObject {}
    static class Parent2Object extends BaseObject {}

    abstract static class BaseContainer<T extends BaseObject> {
        public abstract void foo(T object);
    }
    static class Parent1Container extends BaseContainer<Parent1Object> {
        public void foo(Parent1Object object) {}
    }
    static class Parent2Container extends BaseContainer<Parent2Object> {
        public void foo(Parent2Object object) {}
    }

}
```

---

```
public class BaseClass<T extends BaseContainer> {
    public abstract T createContainer();
}
```

---

I have a method that returns `BaseContainer<BaseObject>`. Unfortunately, instantiating sub-classes of `BaseContainer` results in incompatible types error.

---

I have tried adding casts to the container instantiation, but it leaves ugly unchecked warnings that make me feel like I'm just missing something. I'd like to avoid those and suppress warnings.

If possible, how can I re-write the any of the classes to make the `createContainer()` method work?

Comment: You explain BaseObject and BaseContainer, and they make sense. What is BaseClass?

Comment: @ram A class with the 2 abstract methods foo() and createContainer() using its generic as a parameter and return type respectively.

Comment: Probably, you are taking out some important things to make a simple example. Your list variable is local and not tied to any kind of generics, but you are trying to tie foo method appropriately, which uses this list variable.

Comment: Please show `BaseClass` code

Comment: @ram you're right, it's very simplified, I think adding foo() and List is throwing off the actual problem. I made a sample program with the edited code and it illustrates the problem.

Comment: OK, I see. So, `TestClass`'s `createContainer` method might return either `Parent1Container` or `Parent2Container`, correct? There's no `TestClass1` that returns `Parent1Container` and `TestClass2` that returns `Parent2Container`. Because that should be the way to do it...

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner yes

Comment: Do you have a subclass of BaseClass for each subclass of BaseObject?

Comment: @ram no, i also have no access to BaseClass, it's part of a library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java),

> Neither `List<Number>` nor `List<Integer>` is a `subtype` of the other, even though `Integer` is a subtype of `Number`. So, any method that takes `List<Number>` as a parameter does not accept an argument of `List<Integer>`. If it did, it would be possible to insert a `Number` that is not an `Integer` into it, which violates type safety.

Since `BaseClass` is in a library and you cannot modify it, this case cannot be handled cleanly, i.e. as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Parent1Container` and `Parent2Container` are not exactly `BaseContainer<BaseObject>` but `BaseContainer<? extends BaseObject>`
you need to change the signatures accordingly:

```
public class TestClass extends BaseClass<BaseContainer<? extends BaseObject>> {
    ...
    public BaseContainer<? extends BaseObject> createConstructor() {
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
           return new Parent1Container();
        } else {
           return new Parent2Container();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

`BaseContainer<BaseObject>` makes reference to all those BaseContainer (including extending classes) instances that are able to "handle" any BaseObject, where handle is a blanket-term for all the operations it may do with that type-argument.

In contrast `BaseContainer<? extends BaseObject>` refer to those BaseContainer instances that are meant to handle a subset of all BaseObject where the top parent class is unknown (thus the `?`). It that `?` happens to be BaseObject then these two sets would be equivalent.

If your case `?` can be either `Parent1Object` or `Parent2Object` and so you cannot do better than just leave it as `?`.

Comment: I tried this before. Unforetunately, I'm also keeping the containers in a list. I cannot add any ? extends BaseObject items.